# How to skip further execution if exception is catch

Tags: asp.net

I am using web application.I am using aspx page as api.From function I am calling function 2.Both function have try and catch block.

```
 Function1()
    {
      try
      {
        int b = function2()
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
        Response.Write(ex.Tostring());
      }

    }

   public int Function2()
    {
      int a= 0;
      try
      {
        a=8;
       return a;
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
       Response.Write(ex.Tostring());
       return a;
      }

    }
```

I want to skip further execution(function1) if error catch in second funtion.can I use break in second function's catch block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Function2` `catch` block do not `return` but `throw` the exception so it will be again caught in `function1` `catch` block.

```
Function1()
{
    try
    {
        int b = function2()
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Tostring());
    }
}

public int Function2()
{
    int a= 0;
    try
    {
        a=8;
        return a;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Tostring());
        throw; //<----- here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on [break](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-SE/library/adbctzc4.aspx) you can't break in the second function to stop further execution of Function1 in the given example. But you can do something like this.

```
Function1()
{
    try
    {
        int b = function2()
        if (b = 0)
            break; // Or maybe a return of an error.
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Tostring());
    }
}
```